# How to pause video on iframe when page is loaded?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a video displayed on my webpage , i have used iframe to display the video instead of using Video tag because using iframe makes it alot easier to fit video within the parent div.

How i can pause the video from playing once the page is loaded ?

HTML :

```
 <div class="parent">
<iframe class="video" id="player" src="try.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{
position:fixed;
margin:0;
width:90px;
height:90px;
overflow: hidden;
}


.video{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Nothing in your code suggests that the video, such that it is, plays automatically. Do you own the page that is within the iframe?

Comment: @zer00ne yes i do , and yes it plays automatically once the page is loaded and i need to pause it .

Comment: If you own both pages then you have a ton of options available to you. Post the code for the child page and I'll know what you'll need to do. Without seeing your child page, I'd have to guess. My best guess would be that have you have the `autoplay` attribute on the `<video>` tag. If you do, remove it, if you don't I'll need the code of the child page.